# How Can I use a ComboBox bound to a null record in a detail section?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

In a form, I am displaying rows of data in the detail section. 
Around 5% of the rows might actually have a float value in one column that I need to be displayed as a combobox. The column in question results from a left join, so it may have a float, or it may be null with no existing record behind it. I don't want to have 100000 rows added to a table just to show a zero in the combobox on the outside chance that a user actually displays that particular record. Yes, I can add the rows, then delete them later, but that seems stupid. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the combobox to default to a zero for each row, and still be selectable. Basically for each row, show the value if there is one, zero otherwise, and let the user select a new value if they want. 
The VBA side is easy. I can totally create the row if a non-zero value is selected, and delete the row if the user changes it to 0. Ideal would be to bind  a combobox to NZ(myField,0), or something similar. When I tried that, the combobox was not selectable.

Right now my combobox is selectable, allows the users to change the value, but shows a blank, not zero if the column is null.

The SQL the form is bound to:

SELECT  dbo.PersonClasses.ClassID,  dbo.ClassDates.ClassDate, dbo.PersonClassHours.ClassHours
FROM dbo.PersonClasses 
INNER JOIN dbo.ClassDates ON dbo.PersonClasses.ClassID = dbo.ClassDates.ClassID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PersonClassHours ON dbo.People.PersonID = dbo.PersonClassHours.PersonID AND dbo.ClassDates.ClassID = dbo.PersonClassHours.ClassID AND dbo.ClassDates.ClassDate = dbo.PersonClassHours.ClassDate

I am looking to represent ClassHours as a Combobox for each record on the form with valid selections being 0,.5,1,1.5,2,2.5. To keep it simple for the users, I want 0 to be preselected. This is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Set combobox DefaultValue to have 0 preselected. Use Nz() or IIf() in query on whatever field has Null to provide 0 as alternate value. Why have query design result in null records anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `Format` property of the combobox to

```
@;\0
```

This will display a zero if the field value is `Null`. Otherwise the actual value.

Other properties which will also need to be set are the `Row Source Type` to `Value List` and `Row Source` to `0;0.5;1;1.5;2;2.5`

Using a function, such as `Nz()`, in your query to change the value of the field, actually creates a new field, which is read-only.

In your case you need the field to be updateable, so one of your options is to play around with the `Format` propery, or `Conditional Formatting`.

Comment: That format property trick is exactly what is was looking for. I now have a zero, or the actual value.   Now, for for some reason, it is not letting me select any new values unless there is a previously populated value- Which I thought I had fixed when it was displaying blanks.... But at least with the format piece figured out, I am halfway there!. Thanks! I have marked this as the answer.